# SubscribeOnDispatcher in Silverlight/WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, system.reactive

In what cases I really have a necessity to use an IObservable<>.SubscribeOnDispatcher method in Silverlight/WPF applications? I.e. I'm asking for particular cases, when this call is a must.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a must when these conditions are true:

1. Your Observable is based on something that generates callbacks/events that are not already guaranteed to be be on the main UI thread (eg. `HttpWebRequest`)
2. The code that responds to the arrival these items needs to manipulate UI elements
3. Other code in the chain must not execute until the previous manipulations of UI elements are complete.

If 1 isn't true then things arrive from it on the UI thread already.  If 2 isn't true then there being on the UI thread isn't important.  If 3 isn't true then code at stage 2 could `BeginInvoke` some of its UI work on the `Dispatcher` itself.